# Interfacing Random Numbers in Typescript

Tags: typescript, random

I have a type

`type DiceNumber = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6`

for part of a react state. I want to set the state to a random number between 1 and 6, so I try this

`const dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;`

but I get

`Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'DiceNumber'`.

I understand why, but is there a way around this? Can I guarantee random numbers to fit the type?

Comment: can you add the code that causes `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'DiceNumber'.?

Comment: @jessh It's just setState, so my component uses the ```DiceNumber``` type in its state and then set its state to the value ```dice```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type system in TypeScript doesn't know how to represent the outcome of mathematical operations on [numeric literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#numeric-literal-types).  If you start taking numeric literals like `6` or `1` and do math with them, the compiler will widen the answer to `number`.

There are some issues in GitHub that, if implemented, would help here.  There's [microsoft/TypeScript#26382](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26382), asking for arithmetic like `*` and `+` to be reflected in the type system.  There's [microsoft/TypeScript#15480](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15480), asking for numeric *ranges* as types, which could possibly represent the fact that `Math.random()` outputs numbers between `0` (inclusive) and `1`(exclusive).  And there's [microsoft/TypeScript#4639](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4639), asking for integer types, which could possibly make sense of what `Math.floor()` does. All of these are fairly old issues and it's not clear when or if they will ever become features.  For now, the type system sees `Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1` as just a `number`.  *You* know it will be of type `DiceNumber`, but the compiler doesn't.

It's in situations like this, where you know something about the type of a value that the compiler doesn't, where a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) is useful.  You can just *tell* the compiler that the expression is of type `DiceNumber`:

```
const dice = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1) as DiceNumber; // okay
```

This works, and you can move on with treating `dice` like a union of six numeric literals.  Of course, type assertions are easily abused, since you can easily lie to the compiler:

```
const brokenDice = 7 as DiceNumber; // whoopsie
```

so type assertions are best used judiciously.  When you use a type assertion, you're taking some responsibility for type safety away from the compiler, and taking on that responsibility yourself.  So be careful!

---

Anyway, I hope that helps.  I'm not 100% sure you will find `DiceNumber` a very useful type, since the fact that the compiler can't do math with numeric literals means that `1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6` can only really be used with things like `switch`/`case` statements or `if`/`else` statements that check for particular values.  There's no built-in way to, say, add two `DiceNumber` values and have the compiler see that you now have a value of type `2 | 3 | ... | 11 | 12`.  So you might find yourself constantly using type assertions to narrow types from `number` back to your custom numeric literal unions.  At which point it's not really helping you all that much.  But that's up to you and your use case, I guess.

Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgYwgOQK4FsBGEBOUC8UAjFAD5QBMZUAzNQCzUCs1AbANwCwAUAgPYA7AM7AoAE0TRCACgCyAQ2AALAHQAzADZ8+OOYtU55AsX3TSAlFABUUVpYDUxS-KGxJaLLi7ce-YaMwcPgBrCAF4JAIoAHYoFzckD2wcdigAejSoAHclbTAhOAgeHiggA)

Comment: Wow thanks so much for all of the information @jcalz, that's great to know!